# Smooth CSS Animation scroll-up?

Tags: css, css-animations

I use this css code to be able to scroll text automatically if it takes up to much space on the page. Using a javascript function which adds the class below if it does.

The scrolling works great, but I have performance issues. It moves pretty inconsistent. A bit choppy and laggy. Is there anything I can do to make it scroll smoother?
I have tried on Chrome and Firefox on Windows, but also Chrome and Firefox on Android, and performance on Android is far worse.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/zc12L4ka/

```
.vscroll {
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
  /* Starting position */
  -moz-transform:translateY(100%);
  -webkit-transform:translateY(100%);
  transform:translateY(100%);
  /* Apply animation to this element */
  -moz-animation: scroll-up 25s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: scroll-up 25s linear infinite;
  animation: scroll-up 25s linear infinite;
 }
 /* Move it (define the animation) */
 @-moz-keyframes scroll-up {
  0%   { -moz-transform: translateY(100%); }
  100% { -moz-transform: translateY(-100%); }
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes scroll-up {
  0%   { -webkit-transform: translateY(100%); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%); }
 }
 @keyframes scroll-up {
  0%   {
  -moz-transform: translateY(100%); /* Browser bug fix */
  -webkit-transform: translateY(100%); /* Browser bug fix */
  transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  100% {
  -moz-transform: translateY(-100%); /* Browser bug fix */
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%); /* Browser bug fix */
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
}
```

Comment: [Opinion] _“I use this css code to be able to scroll text automatically if it takes up to much space on the page.”_ - rather bad idea to begin with; you don’t know the reading speed of your page visitors. It might be too fast for some, and seem unnervingly slow to others.

Comment: The page is not scrollable, and static. So that's not an issue. The real issue here is the choppy scrolling that occurs.

Comment: Also, as explained in my first post it is more choppy with Chrome and Firefox on Android. All in all, it doesn't look smooth. And I am looking for tips to improve the performance.

Comment: @joq3 This is an interesting issue because transforms / translates ( I believe ) leverages GPU instead of CPU so you shouldn't be getting any repainting or reflowing: https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a 

It might be that the android device you're testing on has a problem with. It sounds like you're doing a display ad type thing -- is the android device what you'll be using in the field?

Comment: @MathiasRechtzigel I have tried multiple Android devices ranging from tablets, phones to TV boxes. All display the same issue with a not so smooth animation. And I feel like even on PC it is not 100% smooth. I will use both PC and Android devices in the field.